# Can't modify XNA Vector components

Tags: c#, xna

I have a class called Sprite, and ballSprite is an instance of that class. Sprite has a Vector2 property called Position.

I'm trying to increment the Vector's X component like so:

```
ballSprite.Position.X++;
```

but it causes this error:

```
Cannot modify the return value of 'WindowsGame1.Sprite.Position' because it is not a variable
```

Is it not possible to set components like this? The tooltip for the X and Y fields says "Get or set ..." so I can't see why this isn't working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `ballSprite.Position` returns a struct, so when you access it, it creates a copy of it due to the value semantics. ++ attempts to modify that value, but it'll be modifying a temporary copy - not the actual struct stored in your Sprite.

You have to take the value from reading the Position and put it into a local variable, change that local variable, and then assign the local variable back into Position, or use some other, similar way of doing it (maybe hiding it as some `IncrementX` method).

```
Vector2D v;
v = ballSprite.Position;
v.X++;
ballSprite.Position = v;
```

Another, more generic solution, might be to add another Vector2 to your Position. The + operator is overloaded, so you could create a new vector with the change you want, and then add that to the vector instead of updating the indiviudal components one at a time.

Comment: ballSprite.Position.X = ballSprite.Position.X + 1; doesn't work either - same error. :( Isn't that exactly the same as ballSprite.Position.X++ anyway?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking straight there. I've fixed it.

Comment: Okay, looks like it's solved. This issue is kinda annoying. 

Thanks. I'll probably just add two vectors. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
 Position = new Vector2(Position.X + 1, Position.Y );
```

or

```
 Position += new Vector2( 1.0f, 0.0f );
```

or

```
 Position.X += 1.0f;
```

Comment: So is the summary of the X and Y fields a bug? 

    // // Summary: // Gets or sets the y-component of the vector. 

Either way, thanks!

Comment: Nope, I was mistaken, you just need to make sure you are adding a float with the f at the end.

Comment: ballSprite.Position.X += 0.1f; That still gives me the same error. Besides, if the error was caused by a type problem, surely the error would say something about it?

Comment: I just tested code like that in one of my projects and it works as expected. It must have something to do with your sprite class.

Comment: It can't be because even this doesn't work: new Vector2().X += 0.1f;

What version of XNA are you using?

Comment: @Maynza: It's because structs have value-type semantics and reading the property returns a temporary copy, not the specific piece of memory which is stored in the class. @Matt: Did you ONLY write that part for your line? I'm pretty sure `new Vector2()` will be considered a temporary copy - and you're not allowed to modify temporary copies of stuff. Try putting the vector into a local variable BEFORE modifying it.

Answer (score 2):

An easy alternative is this:

instead of: `sprite.Position.X = 10;`

use: `sprite.Position = new Vector2(10, sprite.Position.Y);`

instead of: `sprite.Position.Y = 10;`

use: `sprite.Position = new Vector2(sprite.Position.X, 10);`

instead of: `sprite.Position.X += 10;`

use: `sprite.Position += new Vector2(0, 10);`

instead of: `sprite.Position.Y += 10;`

use: `sprite.Position += new Vector2(10, 0);`

Comment: Yep this is exactly the way I do it but with Vector3, seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of  using `new Vector2(...)` to add 2 vectors, you can also use [Vector2.UnitX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.unitx.aspx):

```
ballSprite.Position.X += 1; // error
ballSprite.Position += Vector2.UnitX; // solution
```

It's very useful when you want to move *directional*. For example, if you want to move only horizontal:

```
Vector2 offset = new Vector2(2, 4);
ballsprite.Position += offset * Vector2.UnitX;
```

In this example, the value of `speed.Y` won't be added to the position of the sprite. Why?

```
offset    ==   new Vector2(2, 4)
UnitX     ==   new Vector2(1, 0)
--------------------------------
The above Vectors are multiplied
which results into the following
--------------------------------
offset       *  UnitX
(X: 2, Y: 4) *  (X: 1, Y: 0)
(X: 2 * 1,  ...  Y: 4 * 0)
(X: 2, Y: 0)          <-- result
```

Another advantage of doing it this way is *readability*. At least that is what I think. See it for yourself:

```
// multiple ways of incrementing ballspeeds X coordinate.
ballSprite.Position += Vector2.UnitX;
ballSprite.Position += new Vector2(1, 0);
ballSprite.Position = new Vector2(ballSprite.Position.X + 1, ballSprite.Position.Y);

Vector2 temp = ballSprite.Position;
temp.X++;
ballSprite.Position = temp;
```

Of course, there is also a [Vector2.UnitY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.unity.aspx) for vertical movement. Combine these static fields together with [Vector2.Zero](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.zero.aspx) and [Vector2.One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.one.aspx), and you can write easy-to-understand code.

When I'm working with `Vector2`s and directions, I use the following table:

```
             <---  X coordinate  --->
       -1                0               +1
                |                |                
  -Vector2.One  | -Vector2.UnitY |                  -1
  (X:-1, Y:-1)  |  (X: 0, Y:-1)  |                
                |                |                      ^
----------------+----------------+----------------      |
                |                |                
 -Vector2.UnitX |  Vector2.Zero  | +Vector2.UnitX    0  Y coordinate
  (X:-1, Y: 0)  |  (X: 0, Y: 0)  |  (X:+1, Y: 0)  
                |                |                      |
----------------+----------------+----------------      V
                |                |                
                | +Vector2.UnitY |  +Vector2.One    +1
                |  (X: 0, Y:+1)  |  (X:+1, Y:+1)  
                |                |
```