# Cannot Modify Return Value because It is not a Variable

Tags: c#, vector, xna, return, pass-by-value

Pass by Value strikes again!!

```
player.Vector.X += player.Speed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
```

does not work.

```
Vector2 v = player.Vector;
v.X -= player.Speed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
player.Vector = v;
```

fixes this problem.

This is explained here: [Can't modify XNA Vector components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534574/cant-modify-xna-vector-components)

The answer was very well explained and works just fine, but it has been 4 years since it was posted.  **My question is, since its been 4 years, is there a better way to fix this problem now?**

I have about 100 lines of this I need to fix, and was hoping there was some sort of shortcut by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably never going to be a "shortcut" for this since it's a feature of the fundamental difference between value types and reference types.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly modify a `Vector`'s X, Y, Z, etc properties in XNA. What you can try is creating a new `Vector2` based off the `player`'s like this. This would reduce your 3 lines of code to **1** (if that's what your going for):

```
player.Vector = New Vector2(player.Vector.X - player.Speed * 
    (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds, player.Vector.Y);
```

This should do exactly what the "fix" did, except in one line. The same idea would apply to `Vector3` or `Vector4`, and if you wanted to modify more than one property of the vector.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood the question, but I thought you wanted to shorten the code. To answer your question more directly: no, there's no way to change a single component of a vector in XNA. :)

Comment: Sure. sorry I didn't understand it at first. (btw, I had downvoted the answer cuz I thought it really should be a comment, but once I realized you thought it was good I undownvoted it:).)