# Vector2 property set by X or Y

Tags: c#, variables, properties, xna

I would like to ask how to define property Vector2 so I could do this property to store data through coordinate X or Y as follows:

```
MyProperty.X = 1;
MyProperty.Y = 2;
```

at now my property code look like this:

```
Vector2 myProperty;
public Vector2 MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return myProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                myProperty = value;
            }
        }
```

but I cant set value to X or Y coord I can only set new Vector2.

Comment: what is the type of `myProperty` ?? it should be **Vector2** or some type that contains `X` and `Y` fields

Comment: it is variable: Vector2 myProperty;

Comment: If you make myProperty public, you will be able to do anything with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly modify (or mutate) `Vector2`'s properties in XNA. What you have to do instead is something like this:

```
float somevariable = 1f;
MyProperty = new Vector2(MyProperty.X + somevariable, MyProperty.Y - somevariable);
```

Or

```
var X = MyProperty.X + 1f;
MyProperty = new Vector2(X, MyProperty.Y);
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566799/cannot-modify-return-value-because-it-is-not-a-variable/21566881) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534574/cant-modify-xna-vector-components)